# Move actionscript from timeline to external .as file

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I got a serius problem coz i dont know so much about as3.

I have an actionscript code in a project that in timeline Frame one and the code is:

```
stop();


    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.errors.IOError;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;


    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;


import com.drooza.*;
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;

const thumbWidth:int = 90;
const numThumbsShown:int = 5;

var thumb_array:Array = [];
var thumbContainer:Sprite = new Sprite(), 
    pictureContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

var leftMostThumb:int = 0; //for sliding thumbs
var currentThumb:int = 0;
var thumbsXML:XMLReader = new XMLReader("gallery.xml");

var thumbcurrentThumbList:XMLList;
var pictureLoader:Loader;


//var _browseBtn: SimpleButton;


thumbsXML.init();
thumbsXML.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbCompleteHandler);

pictureContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoLargePicture);
pictureContainer.buttonMode = true;
pictureContainer.mouseChildren = false;
pictureContainer.x = 10;
pictureContainer.y = 10;

addChild(pictureContainer);
addChildAt(thumbContainer, getChildIndex(mask_mc) - 1);

with(thumbContainer)
{
    mask = mask_mc;
    x = mask_mc.x;
    y = mask_mc.y;
}

thumbsXML.parseXML = function() {
    clearContainer(thumbContainer);

    try {
//  <gallery albumDir="albums/">
//  <album galleryDir="album-1/" thumbDir="thumbs/" sizedDir="sized/" largeDir="large/">
//      <image url="2009-Lotus-Evora-Front-1280x960.jpg"><![CDATA[Caption for the image 1]]></image>
        trace(thumbsXML.xmlData..album.length() + " albums found.");

        for each(var album:XML in thumbsXML.xmlData..album)
        {
            trace("ALBUM: \n" + album);
            for each(var image:XML in album.image)
            {
                trace("THUMB\n" + image);
                //create client thumbs and add them to container
                var thumb:Thumb = new Thumb();
                thumb.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(thumb);
                thumb.x = (thumbContainer.numChildren * (thumbWidth + 10));

                thumb.imageLoader.loadImage(thumbsXML.xmlData.@albumDir + album.@dir + album.@galleryDir + album.@thumbDir + image.@url);
                thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, thumbClickHandler);
                thumbContainer.addChild(thumb);
                thumb_array[thumb_array.length] = thumb;

                thumb.item = new Item({
                      image:thumbsXML.xmlData.@albumDir + album.@dir + album.@galleryDir + album.@largeDir + image.@url,
                      sized:thumbsXML.xmlData.@albumDir + album.@dir + album.@galleryDir + album.@sizedDir + image.@url,
                      thumb:thumbsXML.xmlData.@albumDir + album.@dir + album.@galleryDir + album.@thumbDir + image.@url, 
                      description:image.text()
                      });


            }
        }

        leftArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveLeft);
        rightArrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveRight);

        showThumbContents();
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    { 
        trace(":: Error parsing XML.");
        trace("Caught: " + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}





function thumbClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var thumb:Thumb = e.target as Thumb;
    currentThumb = thumbContainer.getChildIndex(thumb);
    showThumbContents();
}

function showThumbContents():void {
    var thumb:Thumb = thumbContainer.getChildAt(currentThumb) as Thumb;
    clearContainer(pictureContainer);
    try
    {
        pictureLoader = new Loader();

        pictureLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumb.item.sized));
        pictureLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorHandler);
        pictureLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
        pictureLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, pictureCompleteHandler);


        pictureContainer.addChild(pictureLoader);
    }
    catch(e:TypeError){
        trace("Error showing thumb contents.\n\t" + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}


function gotoLargePicture(e:MouseEvent = null):void {
    trace("GOTO LARGE PICTURE");
    var thumb:Thumb = thumbContainer.getChildAt(currentThumb) as Thumb; 
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(thumb.item.image), "_blank");
}

function IOErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("IOErrorEvent!:" + e);
}

function onProgressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace("ProgressEvent: " + e);
    loading_mc.visible = true;
}

function pictureCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
    //trace("Complete! " + e);
    //pictureContainer.x = 275 - (pictureContainer.width / 2)
    loading_mc.visible = false; 
}

function adjustThumbs():void {
    var temp:int = 0;
    while(temp <= currentThumb - numThumbsShown)
        temp += numThumbsShown;
    leftMostThumb = temp;

    slideThumbs();
}

function moveLeft(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(leftMostThumb > 0)
        leftMostThumb -= numThumbsShown;
    slideThumbs();
}

function moveRight(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(leftMostThumb < int(thumbContainer.numChildren - numThumbsShown))
        leftMostThumb += numThumbsShown;
    slideThumbs();
}

function slideToThumb(thumbNum:int):void {
    leftMostThumb = thumbNum;
    slideThumbs();
}

function slideThumbs():void {
    var slide:Object = {x:mask_mc.x - leftMostThumb * (thumbWidth + 10), time:.5, transition:"easeOut"};
    Tweener.addTween(thumbContainer, slide);
    //Tweener.addTween(clientTitleContainer, slide);
}

function prevThumb(e:MouseEvent):void {
    currentThumb--;
    if(currentThumb <= 0)
        currentThumb = thumbContainer.numChildren - 1;
    //showDescription();
    showThumbContents();
}

function nextThumb(e:MouseEvent):void {
    currentThumb++;
    if(currentThumb >= thumbContainer.numChildren)
        currentThumb = 0;
    //showDescription();
    showThumbContents();
}

function clearContainer(container:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    while(container.numChildren > 0)
        container.removeChildAt(0);
}

function thumbCompleteHandler(e:Event){ 
    trace("thumbsXML loaded. ");
    thumbsXML.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbCompleteHandler);
}









//_browseBtn = browseBT;// new SimpleButton ( ) ;
//_browseBtn.useHandCursor = true;
browseBT.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.CLICK, _handleMouseEvent ) ;
//_fileFilter = new FileFilter ( "Image", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;" ) ;      


        function _handleMouseEvent ( evt : MouseEvent ) : void
        {

            //_fileRef = new FileReference ( ) ;
            //_fileRef.browse ( [_fileFilter] ) ;
            //_fileRef.addEventListener ( Event.SELECT, _onImageSelect ) ;

            blackmask.blackmastin.gotoAndPlay(2);

        }
```

Now i have another project that i want to put this code but this project loads the actionscript code from an external .as file.

The Code is:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
    import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
    import fl.events.SliderEvent;
    import com.flashcube.Transformer;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var color:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
        private var filter:ColorMatrixFilter;
        private var faceTransform:Transformer;

        public function Main():void
        {
            /* Required to create initial Matrix */

            color.brightness = 0;
            color.contrast = 0;
            color.hue = 0;
            color.saturation = 0;

             var newZIndex = 10;

            /* Add Listeners function */

            addListeners();
            addListeners2();
            addListeners22();

        }

        private final function addListeners():void
        {
            faceTransform                       = new Transformer(image2);
            faceTransform.color                 = 0x000FFF;
            faceTransform.showCenterCircle      = true;
            faceTransform.selectedColor         = 0x000000;
            faceTransform.selectedAlpha         = 0.5;
            faceTransform.allowScaleProportion  = true;
            faceTransform.allowRotateProportion = false;

            colorPanel.brightSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustBrightness);
            colorPanel.contSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustContrast);
            colorPanel.hueSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustHue);
            colorPanel.satSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustSaturation);


        }

        private final function adjustBrightness(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.brightness = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function adjustContrast(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.contrast = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function adjustHue(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.hue = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function adjustSaturation(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.saturation = e.target.value;
            update();
        }

        private final function update():void
        {
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(color.CalculateFinalFlatArray());
            image.filters = [filter];
        }







        private final function addListeners2():void
        {
            colorPanel2.brightSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustBrightness2);
            colorPanel2.contSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustContrast2);
            colorPanel2.hueSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustHue2);
            colorPanel2.satSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, adjustSaturation2);
        }

        private final function adjustBrightness2(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.brightness = e.target.value;
            update2();
        }

        private final function adjustContrast2(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.contrast = e.target.value;
            update2();
        }

        private final function adjustHue2(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.hue = e.target.value;
            update2();
        }

        private final function adjustSaturation2(e:SliderEvent):void
        {
            color.saturation = e.target.value;
            update2();
        }

        private final function update2():void
        {
            filter = new ColorMatrixFilter(color.CalculateFinalFlatArray());
            image2.filters = [filter];
        }


    //-------------------------------------------------

private final function addListeners22():void
        {
image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, friendMaker);
        }

private final function friendMaker(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 //setChildIndex(image2,stage.numChildren-1);
   setChildIndex(image,numChildren+1);
}





    }

}
```

Please is it possible someone to help me to mix the first code int second .as file?

I am attaching a download link with all source files.

In the file AdgustColor in frame on there is the actionscript code that i want to transfare to Main.as File.

In the filescroller.fla there is the original Scroller.

Ofcourse the AdgustColor.fla doesnt work until i remove the actionscript code from the timeline Frame 1.

**DOWNLOAD:** [myfiles](http://www.goldencoupon.gr/test.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be honest with you here. You should start small and read some tutorials on how classes work before you attempt something like this. Although the migration is very easy, when it comes time to revise your code in any way, you will run into issues.

Comment: Ofcourse you are right lostPixels but in my case is there any possibility to help me?

Answer (score 0):

"Mixing" code especially from a class file isn't a very good idea if you don't know what you are doing. I don't think anyone here will be able to answer this question the way you want it answered, which appears to be "Just do it for me". Maybe if you provide what the end result will be someone might just do it for you. There's a lot of code there however so still I doubt you will get a perfect answer. I think the best answer you are going to get is to dig into the code and learn how it functions. In the end you will get a better result because you will know everything about the code and you will have learned something from it that you can apply to other problems. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok guys, i mixed it up and its working great. Thank you for your time!